# Intersection of $\operatorname{Ker}f$ and $G/\operatorname{Ker}f$ is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, exact-sequence

Suppose the short exact sequence of groups
$$\operatorname{Ker}f\rightarrowtail G\twoheadrightarrow G/\operatorname{Ker}f$$
has a right splitting $G/\operatorname{Ker}f\rightarrowtail G$. Then the intersection of $\operatorname{Ker}f$ with $G/\operatorname{Ker}f$ is trivial because any element of $\operatorname{Ker}f$ becomes the unit in $G/\operatorname{Ker}f$.

I'm trying to formulate this in terms of arrows and can't see the light... I think this should quickly follow in any finitely complete pointed regular category, but I just don't see how to use the zeros well.

How to categorically prove the intersection (pullback) of the subobjects $\operatorname{Ker}f$ and $G/\operatorname{Ker}f$ is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a map $a:T\to G$ which factors through both $\ker f$ and $G/\ker f$.  Since $a$ factors through $\ker f$, $fa=0$.  But if $i:G/\ker f\to G$ is the splitting map and we factor $a=ib$ for some $b$, this means $0=fa=fib=b$ and so $a=ib=0$.  That is, $a$ factors uniquely through the zero object.

Comment: I got this far as well, so maybe I am missing something. Shouldn't "zero intersection of subobjects" mean the pullback is actually the initial arrow from the zero object, and not just that it factors (necessarily uniquely) through zero?

Comment: I'm not saying $a$ is the pullback, I'm saying $a$ is an arbitrary map that factors through $\ker f$ and $G/\ker f$.  Any such map factors uniquely through the map $0\to G$, which proves that $0\to G$ is the pullback.

Comment: Ah, so blind of me! Thank you.